# How do I set up my Response object to perform all of the necessary cleanup

Tags: c#, iis

This is my code, my application is in error inadvertently where the application will not load and throws an error. The only way to fix the issue is by recycling the app pool that the application runs under. But, I am wondering if my problem can be resolved by setting up this code correctly? For instance putting it in a using statement, which I am not certain how to do.

```
// Write PDF
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", assessment);
Response.WriteFile(filepath3);
Response.End();
```

I don't know if this is related or not, but this is the Server error:

```
Server Error in '/Apps/LeadAssessmentApp' Application.
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {080D0D78-F421-11D0-A36E-00C04FB950DC} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800401e4 Invalid syntax (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E4 (MK_E_SYNTAX)).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
    
Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {080D0D78-F421-11D0-A36E-00C04FB950DC} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800401e4 Invalid syntax (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E4 (MK_E_SYNTAX)).
    
Source Error:
    
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Comment: "throws an error", so what is that? Rarely you hit something nobody else discussed, so you should talk about that first.

Comment: As Lex said, what's the error? How large is your file, how many responses are trying to work the file at the same time, what are the permissions on the file and does the worker running the app pool have permissions... many things could be happening... [HttpResponse.WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.writefile?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpResponse_WriteFile_System_String_)

Comment: Files are about 500+kb each, right now there is up to 5 people at a time trying to access a file from the same folder. The permissions are set

Comment: Check your web server's event log for errors that may be related and share what you find.

Comment: I checked the logs from IIS and nothing was outstanding, there is a remedy to this, but I am reluctant to use it because other applications use the app pool. the remedy is to change the advanced setting on the app pool "Load User Profile" to be set to true.

Comment: My main question though is how to put the above code into a "using statement" then I can rest assure that I have performed all of the cleanup necessary.

Comment: You didn't post all your code, I'm assuming this `Response` is part of a `Page` object. If so you cannot wrap the response in a `using` statement as you are not instantiating it, the `Page` is actually instantiating it. Instead, just wrap the `Response.WriteFile` method call in a Try/Catch and handle it there. Also, have you considered that the Response.End() call is not your best option? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.end?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The response does not cause COM component errors, please show us the code related to the COM component.